# Error: Unrecognized selector trying to log contents of NSArray

Tags: objective-c, ios7, nsarray

I have this code:

```
//  create the NSMutableArray for appointment objects
NSMutableArray *apptArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];  //  capacity not limited by the 5

CalendarGenerator *cg = [[CalendarGenerator alloc]init];
[apptArray addObject: [cg generateCalendar:period scheduleArray: scheduleArray]];  //  will add good appointment to array

Appointment *aa = [[Appointment alloc]init];
for(int i = 0; i < apptArray.count; i++)  {
    aa = apptArray[i];

    NSLog(@"\n\nstartTime: %@\nendTime: %@\nkey: %@", aa.startTime, aa.endTime, aa.clientKey);
}
```

**UPDATE: **  this is the Appointment.h file:

```
@interface Appointment : NSObject  { 

}

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate *startTime;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate *endTime;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *clientKey;

@end
```

The data looks like this:

[image]

I'm getting this run-time error while debugging in the simulator:

> '-[__NSArrayM startTime]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

I have spent about 3 hours trying different things, non of which work;  and I still don't see what's wrong... I would appreciate it if someone could please help me on this?

Comment: Well.....  It's saying that NSArray doesn't have a method called `startTime`.

Comment: (In the for loop you store an NSArray pointer into `aa`, for some mysterious reason.)

Comment: You're sending `startTime` to an object that you think is an `Appointment`, but which raises an exception about `startTime` being sent to `NSArray`. Ergo, the actual type of the object is likely to be ___________.

Comment: I just updated the question with the def of the Appointments class... you can see they are NOT methods, but rather properties.

Comment: Properties are methods (plus usually an ivar); it's just a different declaration syntax. But the `Appointment` interface is irrelevant.

Comment: its very clear in the log , that 'aa' object is a array. that why you are getting error. but you are using it as Appointment.

Comment: I couldn't see how (and I tried, believe me) I could access the contents of the NSArray in the for loop without removing one of the array's elements, then I used the element to access the data.

Comment: replace this apptArray[i] with [apptArray[i] firstObject] or [apptArray[i] objectAtIndex:0]. it should work. but its temporary solution. you have to fix the structure of apptArray.

Comment: pawan:  thank you... please rewrite your comment as an answer so I can mark it as the solution.  I appreciate everybody's time, I really do!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like generateCalendar:scheduleArray: returns an array, not an appointment. Also it's not good to allocate appointment out of for cycle, use for..in cycle instead. Example:

```
NSMutableArray *apptArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

CalendarGenerator *cg = [[CalendarGenerator alloc] init];
[apptArray addObjectsFromArray:[cg generateCalendar:period scheduleArray:scheduleArray]];

for(Appointment *appointment in apptArray)
{
    NSLog(@"\n\nstartTime: %@\nendTime: %@\nkey: %@", appointment.startTime, appointment.endTime, appointment.clientKey);
}
```

Comment: So Josh... how do I fix this?  The NSLog is just to a) see what's in the array and b) "proof of concept" that I can access the data later on when I need it in another class.

Comment: I already wrote that you should use

`[apptArray addObjectsFromArray:[cg generateCalendar:period scheduleArray:scheduleArray]];`

instead of

`[apptArray addObject:[cg generateCalendar:period scheduleArray:scheduleArray]];`

Comment: Thanks Igor... I got it working (removed all the junk and replaced it with your code and this: for(Appointment *aa in apptArray)  works like a champ now!  Thanks again...

Answer (score 1):

its very clear in the log , that 'aa' object is a array. that why you are getting error. but you are using it as Appointment.

replace this apptArray[i] with [apptArray[i] firstObject] or [apptArray[i] objectAtIndex:0]. it should work. but its temporary solution. you have to fix the structure of apptArray.

Comment: pawan: how do I "fix" the structure of apptArray? (I don't see anything wrong with it, but then again, I'm no expert... learning as I go along).  What I want is an array of Appointment classes, if that's possible.

Comment: check the return value of this "[cg generateCalendar:period scheduleArray: scheduleArray]" it should be of type Appointment.